# shuf command isn't random inside of find -exec?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, zsh

```
find dev-other -iname '*.flac' -exec echo {} \; -exec echo "$(ls -p backgrounds | grep -v / | gshuf -n 1)" \;
```

I expect to see the name of a `.flac` file and then a random name of one of the files from `./backgrounds`.

Instead I see this:

```
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0087.flac
Wind.mp3
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0091.flac
Wind.mp3
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0029.flac
Wind.mp3
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0028.flac
Wind.mp3
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0090.flac
Wind.mp3
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0069.flac
Wind.mp3
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0086.flac
Wind.mp3
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0100.flac
Wind.mp3
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0045.flac
Wind.mp3
```

For every file that `find` finds, the same "random" file is chosen from `./backgrounds`.

How can I choose a random file inside a find `-exec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is expanding

```
"$(ls -p backgrounds | grep -v / | gshuf -n 1)"
```

to a single string before executing `find`, which dutifully calls `echo "the same string every time"`.

One way to get what you want is to run the `echo` inside a new shell every time, e.g.

```
find dev-other -iname '*.flac' -print \
    -exec sh -c 'ls -p backgrounds | grep -v / | gshuf -n 1' \;
```

Alternately, don't try to do this work in `find` - other tools are better suited. For example, `awk` can easily pass through data and also run a command on every line.

```
find dev-other -iname '*.flac' |
    awk '1;{system("ls -p backgrounds | grep -v / | gshuf -n 1")}'
```

Comment: I suspected it might have been that, didn't know I could use a separate shell to circumvent it though. Is there a more concise way than that?

Comment: @minseong Alternative given.